# How to add ASP.Net identity to Asp.Net Core when webApi template is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have created a .NET Core project with WebApi template selected includes no authentication. I want to add ASP.NET identity in it for role based authorization. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Identity is poorly suited for web APIs. Look into JwtBearer instead.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Edit:

This answers the question but generally speaking I agree with the comment on the question above - JWT bearer tokens are the best fit for an API, it’s best to understand that option before deciding on the best approach for your use case.

### Original Answer

This will give you a bear bones webapi with aspnet core identity, first create your project (this assumes you've created a new folder and you're in it):

```
dotnet new webapi
```

Add aspnet core identity:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

Add some database provider to store your data:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

Now add a user type, the simplest version being:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

And a db context, here I'm setting up the connection string within the class but you'd probably want to use DbContextOptions instead:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring
        (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => 
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("your connection string");
}
```

Then in your Startup.cs add the following marked lines:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    //add this: simply creates db if it doesn't exist, no migrations
    using (var context = new IdentityContext())
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //add this: register your db context
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>();

    //and this: add identity and create the db
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //add this
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Note that by default the AddIdentity extension will set the default authentication scheme and add various cookies that you probably don't want in an API, the cut down alternative is as follows (to replace the above AddIdentity call in ConfigureServices):

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => { });
new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(IdentityRole), services)
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
```

This will give you the database side of things, you can then use UserManager and SignInManager to create and authenticate users, to get them use the DI system:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = null;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager = null;

    public MyController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    //etc...
```

And then use as follows:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(
    new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = "bob", 
        Email = "bob@bob.com"
    }, "Test123!");
if (result.Succeeded)
    //do stuff...
```

And:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("bob");
result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, "Test123!", false);
if (result.Succeeded)
    //do stuff...
```

Using `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` instead of `PasswordSignInAsync` will avoid the creation of a cookie if `AddIdentity` is used, if `AddIdentityCore` was also used above, then you must use `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` as `PasswordSignInAsync` will not work as an `IAuthenticationSignInHandler` will not have been setup.

Comment: great answer. Now how do we check if the user is logged in every time we have to call a subsequent method on the API? Should we use the signinmanager.IsSignedIn method?

Comment: good answer however keep in mind that if you follow this answer and add options with dbcontext to services, code will break

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing special the template is doing, all you need is the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core NuGet package and the you should be able to follow from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

Comment: This doc explains the use of Identity.Core for the case when you have WebApp, not a WebApi

Comment: There is no difference between „WebApi“ and „WebApp“ anymore. The doc is accurate. See the prevoius answer.