# Store user accounts in-app for ASP.NET core 3.1 API template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build an API project for ASP.NET Core with individual user accounts but the only option is to *Connect to an existing user store in the cloud.*

[image]

Is there a way to create an asp.net core api project via template just like its asp.net web application (.net framework) counterpart, which has classes like Account controllers, viewmodels and models.
[image]

Comment: There is no identity template in web api application , you can manually adding the package and customize : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001846/5751404

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this but typically you'd use ASP.NET Identity, there are many getting started guides online, I'd advise you to [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)