# How to create a ASP.net Core WEB API Identity Service [Runs on server100] to Authenticate Balzer Server Side web App users [Runs on server200]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I'm planning to create a new web application using ASP.Net Core 5.0 Blazer Server Side template and trying to meet the following requirements:

1. **Web Application should be a stand-alone solution, this Web Application will be hosted on IIS Server200.**
2. **ASP.Net Core 5.0 Web API as Microsoft Identity service should be the stand-alone solution to Authorize and Authenticate Balzer web app users. The Web API will be hosted on IIS Server100.**

The web application should use Microsoft identity web API service for user registration, login, forgot password, creating user roles, etc.

I'm not sure about how the Authentication and Authorization can be done using the Web API service.

Could anyone guide me on how to meet the above requirements? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224177/how-to-add-asp-net-identity-to-asp-net-core-when-webapi-template-is-selected).

Comment: Thank you @YiyiYou, I will refer to the article.